Testing an equality
By series manipulations we can show that
$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(a^n x^n)}{1-ax}dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{nk-1}H_{k}^{(2)}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{a^j}{nk+j},$$
for positive integer $n$ and $a=\pm1$.
I tested this equality for many values of a and n and it works totally fine except for the case when a=-1 and n is an even integer. Here is how I tested it:
    f[a_,n_]:= NIntegrate[PolyLog[2, a^n x^n] /(1 - a x), {x, 0, 1}];

    g[a_,n_]:= NSum[a^(n k - 1) HarmonicNumber[k, 2] Sum[a^j/(n k + j), {j, 1, n}], {k, 1, Infinity}];

    f[-1,2]= 0.238639...        g[-1,2]= 0.25828...


    f[-1,4]= 0.133793...        g[-1,4]= 0.12165... 

and the closed-form generalization I found for the integral matches f[a_,n_] for any value of a and n.
So I think Mathematica does not estimate g[-1,2] or g[-1, even n] correctly. What do you think? Maybe there is a command better than NSum[expression] that estimates the sum more correctly?. I want to know if the equality is correct or not because I want to express g[a,n] in terms of f[a,n], since we have the closed-form expression for f[a,n].

Do you have any idea how fast the infinite sum converges? If it is slow, numerical check is hopeless.

Your claim "we have the closed-form expression for f[a,n]" does not correspond to reality: the sum of a series is an analytic expression, not a closed-form expression (see Wiki for the definitions).

It should be noticed that a = -1; n = 2; NSum[  a^(n k - 1) HarmonicNumber[k, 2]* Sum[a^j/(n k + j), {j, 1, n}], {k,    1, Infinity}] produces a wrong result 0.215692 -0.00526301 I in 14.1 on Windows.

Here is a more exact calculation of the sum of the series which confirms the equality.
a = -1; n = 2;
Sum[a^(n k - 1) HarmonicNumber[k, 2]* 
Sum[a^j/(n k + j), {j, 1, n}], {k, 1, Infinity}]


Sum[(-1)^(-1 + 2*k)*(-(1 + 2*k)^(-1) + (2 + 2*k)^(-1))* HarmonicNumber[k, 2], {k, 1, Infinity}]

It's clear that (-1)^(-1 + 2*k) == -1 for positive integer values of k and FullSimplify[(-1)^(-1 + 2*k),  Assumptions -> k \[Element] PositiveIntegers] proves it.
Now
NSum[(-1) (-(1/(1 + 2 k)) + 1/(2 + 2 k)) HarmonicNumber[k, 2], {k, 1,Infinity}]


0.238639

I leave the case a==-1 and n==4 on your own.

thank you so much ...i wonder why Mathematica cant ignore (-1)^(nk-1) for even n. its very simple fast its equal to -1 for positive integer k.
